# How do i sum 2 binary numbers without converting them to integers?

Tags: python, binary, operation

I need help!

`I need to sum 2 binary numbers without converting them into integers...`

I need to sum these ones:

`0+0`
`0+1`
`1+1`
`11+11`
`110+100`

HELP PLEASE!

Comment: Your question needs more details, and at a minimum pseudocode of what you've already tried... And why not convert them to integers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was no attempt whatsoever by the asker to solve the problem.

Comment: Its for an excersise, and i cant convert the numbers into integers...

Answer (score 0):

Good practice.

```
num1 = '110'
num2 = '1011'

max_len = max(len(num1), len(num2))

result = [0] * max_len

rev_num1 = num1[::-1]
rev_num2 = num2[::-1]

for i in range(len(num1)):
    result[i] = int(rev_num1[i])

over = 0
for i in range(len(num2)):
    result[i] += int(rev_num2[i]) + over

    over = 0
    if result[i] > 1:
        result[i] %= 2
        over = 1
    result[i] %= 2

if over == 1:
    result.append(1)

print(''.join(str(s) for s in result[::-1]))
```